# How to save only time zone without GMT?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone

I am using this code for getting time zone

```
NSMutableArray *arrResult = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ZZZ"];
    [[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:obj];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: myDate];
        NSMutableString *mu = [NSMutableString stringWithString:dateString];
        [mu insertString:@":" atIndex:3];
        NSString *strResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(GMT%@)%@",mu,obj];
        [arrResult addObject:strResult];


    }];
    NSLog(@"%@", arrResult);
```

the response of this code is like this as what i want

```
"(GMT+01:00)Africa/Libreville",
    "(GMT+00:00)Africa/Lome",
    "(GMT+01:00)Africa/Luanda",
    "(GMT+02:00)Africa/Lubumbashi",
    "(GMT+02:00)Africa/Lusaka",
    "(GMT+01:00)Africa/Malabo",
    "(GMT+02:00)Africa/Maputo",
    "(GMT+02:00)Africa/Maseru",
    "(GMT+02:00)Africa/Mbabane",
    "(GMT+03:00)Africa/Mogadishu",
    "(GMT+00:00)Africa/Monrovia",
    "(GMT+03:00)Africa/Nairobi",
    "(GMT+01:00)Africa/Ndjamena",
    "(GMT+01:00)Africa/Niamey",
    "(GMT+00:00)Africa/Nouakchott",
    "(GMT+00:00)Africa/Ouagadougou",
    "(GMT+01:00)Africa/Porto-Novo",
    "(GMT+00:00)Africa/Sao_Tome",
    "(GMT+02:00)Africa/Tripoli",
    "(GMT+01:00)Africa/Tunis",
```

i have to show this type in my label

[image]

but what i have to do is when we click on save only (Africa/Tripoli) this part in the database will be saved , i am not getting how to do this . 
please help me

Comment: NSString *strResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(GMT%@)%@",mu,obj];
 you add GMT string

Comment: Not getting exactly what you want?  do you want specific one time zone from this list?

Comment: no what i am getting time zone it is right but i have to save only Africa/Niamey, this part of the list Not (GMT+01:00)..

Comment: means you don't want `(GMT+01:00)` this bracket in list ?

Comment: i dont want to save this bracket part  @Lion

Comment: i have to do separate this bracket part and other part (GMT+00:00) Atlantic/Azores @MikeAlter

Comment: You can use substring.

Comment: @AayushKatiyar : check my answer if it help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after many try if anyone want this then see here:-

```
NSString *zoneString = @"(GMT+13:00)Pacific/Tongatapu"

 NSUInteger location = [zoneString rangeOfString:@")"].location+1;

    NSLog(@"Trimed string:%@",[zoneString substringFromIndex:location]);

 Trimed string:Pacific/Tongatapu
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `(GMT+01:00)` this bracket in list then you can make string like,

```
  NSString *strResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj];
    [arrResult addObject:strResult];
```

So, that bracket part will not come.

If you want that bracket part and name both together also for different task then you can make another array called `arrResult2` and make another string called `strResult2` and do as i mentioned above.

So, you have two arrays. one(arrResult) have both that bracket and names and one(arrResult2) have names only.

If you want to separate string then,

```
NSString *str = @"(GMT+00:00)Africa/Lome";

NSString *newStr = [str substringFromIndex:11];

NSLog(@"new str : %@",newStr);
```

I found that every string have closing bracket at `11th index`, so you can use it to get sub string from original one.

Hope this will help :)